# Confused using ctype pointers with memmove in Python

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes

Consider the following Python

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> from ctypes.wintypes import *
>>> class _Filename(Structure):
...     _fields_ = [("NameLengthInBytes",  USHORT),
...                 ("Name",               WCHAR * 1)]
...
>>> req = create_string_buffer(20)
>>> preq = cast(req, POINTER(_Filename))
>>> req
<ctypes.c_char_Array_20 object at 0x0000000002038DC8>
>>> preq.contents
<__main__._Filename object at 0x0000000002038EC8>
>>> preq.contents.NameLengthInBytes = 10
>>> memmove(preq.contents.Name, u"ABCDE", 10)
31932464L
>>> memoryview(req).tobytes()
'\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> preq.contents.Name=u"Z"
>>> memoryview(req).tobytes()
'\n\x00Z\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I'm confused.  I would expect the address of the *contents* of *preq* to be the same as *req*.  At least that is what I thought **cast** would do.

What I would like to do is create a contiguous block of memory that contains the *NameLengthInBytes* followed immediately by a wide characters string of some arbitrary length.  I would like to write the code so that it depends on the field names of *_Filename*, so that if the definition of *_Filename* changes (say by adding an additionally field before Name) the code would still copy to the correct buffer location.

Can anyone help me understand how Python and ctypes manipulate memory directly and how I can achieve my desired goal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have figured out my own question.

First I found a hint [here](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#pointers):

> Note that ctypes does not have OOR (original object return), it
>   constructs a new, equivalent object each time you retrieve an
>   attribute:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> i = c_int(42)
>>> pi = pointer(i)
>>> pi.contents is i
False
>>> pi.contents is pi.contents
False
>>>
```

This explains why req and preq.contents are different.

The next issue was how to get the address I needed.  I came up with this function:

```
def PackFilename(fn):
     bytes = len(fn) * sizeof(WCHAR)
     needed = sizeof(_Filename) + bytes
     req = create_string_buffer(needed)
     preq = cast(req, POINTER(_Filename))
     preq.contents.NameLengthInBytes = bytes
     memmove(addressof(preq[0]) + _Filename.Name.offset, fn, bytes)
     return preq.contents, needed
```

Note that you have to take the pointed to _Filename then add the appropriate offset to calculate the address needed for memmove.

Usage is like so:

```
>>> j,js=PackFilename(u"c:\\jae\\temp")
>>> j
<__main__._Filename object at 0x0000000001FF8DC8>
>>> js
26
>>> j.NameLengthInBytes
22
>>> j.Name
u'c'
>>> wstring_at(addressof(j) + _Filename.Name.offset, j.NameLengthInBytes/sizeof(WCHAR))
u'c:\\jae\\temp'
```

Note that to unpack the Name field you have to reverse what you did in the pack.  That can be put into an UnpackFilename function:

```
def UnpackFilename(fn):
    if type(fn) is _Filename:
        size = fn.NameLengthInBytes / sizeof(WCHAR)
        return wstring_at(addressof(fn) + _Filename.Name.offset, size)
    else:
        log.debug("Unexpected argument type: %s", type(fn))
        raise TypeError()
```

I determined that all the bytes were a contiguous block by checking the contents (using memoryview(req).tobytes()) in the PackFilename function.